# Завершение процессов порожденных скриптом, запущенным через QProcess

Tags: qt, shell, qprocess

Если из консоли запустить скрипт, например:

```
#!/bin/sh
#launch_script
some_app_with_eventloop
killall some_app_with_eventloop
```

то при закрытии окна терминала или нажатии `Ctrl`+`C` в процессе выполнения, `some_app_with_eventloop` будет завершена.

Я пытаюсь добиться такого же поведения при запуске подобного скрипта через `QProcess`.

```
void onstart()
{
  m_process = new QProcess();
  m_process->setProgram(launch_script);
  m_process->start()
}

void onstop()
{
  m_process->write("^C");
  m_process->write("exit");
  m_process->waitForBytesWritten();
  m_process->terminate();
  QTimer::singleshot(1000, m_process, QProcess::deleteLater);
}
```

Но процесс `sh` все время завершается, оставив `some_app_with_eventloop` работающей.
Как добиться такой же реакции, как нажатие `Ctrl`+`C` или закрытие окна терминала?

Comment: Попробуй через метод QProcess::kill() `On Windows, kill() uses TerminateProcess, and on Unix and macOS, the SIGKILL signal is sent to the process.`

Comment: kill неявно вызывается в деструкторе QProcess. И, вероятно, это именно тот жесткий сценарий, который я хочу обойти.